# Bash if command not found

Tags: bash

пишу небольшой скрипт на bash'e и не могу понять, почему выдаёт ошибку

```
#!/bin/bash

if [["$1" -eq '']]
then
    echo 'enter your value (max = 4882)'
    read parametyr
    echo $parametyr > ...
else
    echo $1 > ...
fi
```

если запускать скрипт без параметра, то все нормально. а если с параметром, то в терминале выводит

```
/usr/local/bin/название_скрипта: line 3: [[4000: command not found
```

(4000 это параметр)

Comment: А если переписать строку с if, добавив пробелы?

      if [[ "$1" -eq '' ]]

Comment: пробел убрал сообщение в терминале. большое спасибо :)
не думал, что bash к такому чувствителен :((

Comment: @melodicwing,

    $#

это количество параметров, часто удобней (и правильней) при анализе  пользоваться им.

Answer (score 2):

может лучше не "-eq", а 
"-z" - строка "пустая", т.е. имеет нулевую длину, или 
"-n" - строка не "пустая".

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo 'enter your value (max = 4882)'
    read parametyr
    echo $parametyr > ...
else
    echo $1 > ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте пробелы после `[[` и до `]]`:

```
if [[ "$1" -eq '' ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что если вы запустите

```
readlink -f $(which sh)
```

вы не получите Bash в качестве возвращаемого значения, а Dash. У вас есть правильная преамбула, но это имеет значение только при запуске скрипта как ./test.sh после его выполнения.

Теперь вы принудительно запускаете скрипт через интерпретатор sh , который, вероятно, является Dash, а конструкция [[]] является специфичной для Bash.

Вот почему? Если вы просто замените двойные скобки одиночными (и измените #!/bin/bash на #!/bin/sh , так как ваш скрипт теперь использует только функции POSIX), он должен выполняться по назначению.

Демонстрация на Debian, test.sh с содержимым:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "string" == "string" ]]; then
    echo This is Bash
fi
```

это происходит:

```
$ readlink -f $(which sh)
/bin/dash
$ sh test.sh 
test.sh: 2: test.sh: [[: not found
$ bash test.sh 
This is Bash
$ chmod 755 test.sh
$ ./test.sh
This is Bash
```

[источник](https://superuser.com/questions/552016/bash-script-not-found)